# how to suppress report footer if there is no value

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

Please see my image below

[image: Report Footer]

In my crystal report, there is sum value as total. I'd like to show it at the end of report. So I put this to Report Footer Section. If a report has more than a page, every single page , except last page, show a blank row. Please share me how to suppress like this row.

Answer (score 0):

The **Report Footer** prints once at the end of the document, not on each page. You need to suppress your **Page Footer** instead.